# Temp-Mail-API, How can I solve the async method Issue?

Tags: c#, api

I am currently using this api: https://github.com/RyuzakiH/Temp-Mail-API. I have red the readme but the code that is given does not work, or atleast I can't make it working...

```
using TempMail.API;

static string GetTempmail()
{
var client = TempMailClient.Create();
var client = await TempMailClient.CreateAsync();
var email = client.Email;
return email;
}
```

And I have two errors:
1- client -> a local var or function is already defined
2- await -> the operator 'await' can only be used in an async. method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just correcting the syntax here:

```
static async Task<string> GetTempmail()
{
    var client = await TempMailClient.CreateAsync();
    var email = client.Email;
    return email;
}
```

You were declaring client twice. You also needed to choose whether to call the async or the synchronous method. Here the async is being called. I don't know about the API itself, though.

Comment: The issue is that now I have this code:
(In another method)

            string mail = Convert.ToString(GetTempmail());
            Console.WriteLine("This will be the email:" + mail);

But the mail string is : :System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[System.String,nulled.to_money_maker_bot.Program+<GetTempmail>d__6]

Moreover it creates an error in the first line of the async method:

System.NullReferenceException : 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: You have to await the call: `string mail = await GetTempmail();`. No need to convert because the method already returns a string.